# BizTalk connectivity issue to SQL during VM snapshot

Tags: sql, vmware, biztalk

We have one VM for BizTalk and a separate VM for the SQL backend. We are using Veeam for backups which basically kicks off a snapshot of the VM. When this snapshot is being finalized on the SQL VM, BizTalk services on the application server fail. Usually they restart automatically but sometimes this requires manual intervention to start the services. The error below is logged on the BizTalk server.

Is there any timeout setting or config changes that will allow BizTalk services to stay up during the snapshot process?

An error occurred that requires the BizTalk service to terminate. The most common causes are the following:
 1) An unexpected out of memory error.
 OR
 2) An inability to connect or a loss of connectivity to one of the BizTalk databases. 
 The service will shutdown and auto-restart in 1 minute. If the problematic database remains unavailable, this cycle will repeat.

Error message: [DBNETLIB][ConnectionRead (recv()).]General network error. Check your network documentation.
 Error source:

BizTalk host name: BizTalkServerApplication
 Windows service name: BTSSvc$BizTalkServerApplication

Comment: BizTalk Server 2009 or 2010?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We experienced the same situation and error with both BizTalk 2009 and BizTalk 2013, each set up with two App servers and one SQL DB server.

When our VMware does the final step of the Snapshot backup on the Application servers, it freezes the application server for about 10 seconds, preventing it from receiving packets.  On SQL Server 2008 and 2012, it by default will send out keep-alive packets to the clients every 30 seconds (30,000 ms). If the SQL server fails to receive a response back from the App server, it will send out 5 retries (default setting) of the keep-alive request 1 second (1,000 ms) apart.  If SQL still does not receive the response back, it will terminate the connection, which will cause the BizTalk hosts on the App server to reset, and in our case, when our German-made ERP system sends its EDI documents over to BizTalk during that reset period, the transmission will fail.

We trapped the issue by running NetMon on the DB and App servers, waiting for the next error message.  Upon inspection, we see the five SQL keep-alive packets being sent to the App servers 1 second apart, and at the same time there were NO packets at all received on the Application server.  At first guess, one might think they were "just dropped network packets", which is rarely the case.  We then made the correlation to the timing of the VM Snapshots, and now confirm each time the snapshot finishes each day, the App servers freeze.

As a Short-to-mid-term workaround, we raised the number of retries SQL attempts before declaring a connection dead, (5 by default), by adding the registry value TcpMaxDataRetransmissions and setting it to 30 (thus 30 seconds before SQL declares the client unresponsive). This has masked the problem for now for us, and use at your own discretion.

We are also looking at an Agent-based version of the VM Snapshot, which may alleviate the condition of freezing the server.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any timeout setting or config changes that will allow BizTalk services to stay up during the snapshot process?

Not that I am aware of, however you might want to Google config options in the *btsntsvc.exe.config* file which is located in your BizTalk installation directory.

All messages that pass through BizTalk are written to the BizTalkMsgBoxDb and its other databases are involved if you are running tracking, BAM etc. The only service that can cache 'stuff' and handle a database outage is the Enterprise Single Sign-On (ESSO) Service. BizTalk therefore needs a persistent connection to the database server to remain 'up', hence why your Host Instance (BizTalkServerApplication) is stopping - it simply wouldn't be able to process messages if the database wasn't there.

I would add that your approach to back-ups probably isn't supported by Microsoft and I would further suggest that you seriously consider whether an approach that takes your database server offline during the backup is viable?

BizTalk has a pretty robust backup solution for its various databases built into the product, and I would recommend that you take a look at using this *supported* method.

If you do need to take snapshots of the database system - say once a night - you might want to consider stopping the BizTalk Host Instances, performing the snapshot, and then re-starting the Host Instances through some scripted task.

You might also want to consider checking whether there are any hotfixes for your version of BizTalk Server included in a Cumulative Update that might help address your problem.